# Upload a file in python/Django

Tags: python, django, web-services, file-upload

I have an issue, I'm using django rest framework and I need to submit a image to server using a webservice, however I don't find anything like I actually need, I would like just to provide the location of the file and let the service do the work uploading it, is there a way I can achieve that?, ofc I will only will save the filepath on DB

```
class AdvertisementData(EmbeddedDocument):
 id = ObjectIdField(null=False, primary_key=True)
 brand = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
 name = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
 description = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
 image = StringField(required=False)//HERE THE FILEPATH
 active = BooleanField(required=True)
 target = EmbeddedDocumentField('TargetData')
```

and I'm supposed to do it during this serializer

```
class AdvertisementDataCreateSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
brand = serializers.CharField(required=True)
name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
description = serializers.CharField(required=True)
image = serializers.CharField(required=True)
active = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
target = TargetDataSerializer(required=True)


class Meta:
    model = AdvertisementData
    fields = ('brand', 'name','description','image','active','target')
def create(self,validated_data,**kwargs):
    vendor_id = VendorData.objects.get(vendorAuth__idp=self.context['request'].user.id)
    print(vendor_id.id)
    advertisement = AdvertisementData(id=ObjectId(), brand=self.data.get('brand'), name=self.data.get('name'),
              description=self.data.get('description'),image=self.data.get('image'), active=self.data.get('active'))
    targetaux = self.data.get('target')     
    target = TargetData(id=ObjectId(),minAge=targetaux['minAge'],maxAge=targetaux['maxAge'],gender=targetaux['gender'])
    advertisement.target = target
    vendor_id.advertisements.append(advertisement)
    vendor_id.save()
    #advertisement =  [x for x in vendor_id.advertisements if x.id == ObjectId((advertisement.id))]

    vendor_id.save()
    return advertisement
```

however I have no Idea that much how to do it I'm able to provide the full path to file location but no idea how to submit it.

Comment: where are you uploading the image to?

Comment: Please add some more of your code and describe the occured problem better so we can have a proper look on what your actual problem is. Right now youre only showing a class declaration which doesnt seem to show what could be wrong.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi to a directory in server :/

Answer (score 0):

At the very end I found a neat solution for the model is like this

```
class AdvertisementData(EmbeddedDocument):
id = ObjectIdField(null=False, primary_key=True)
brand = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
name = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
description = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
image = ImageField(required=False)
active = BooleanField(required=True)
target = EmbeddedDocumentField('TargetData')


class AdvertisementDataCreateValidatorSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
brand = serializers.CharField(required=True)
name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
description = serializers.CharField(required=True)
image = serializers.CharField(required=True)
active = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
target = TargetDataSerializer
#C:\Users\GrupoBECM09\Pictures\Test

class Meta:
    model = AdvertisementData
    fields = ('brand', 'name','description','image','active','target')
```

It was hard to get to this solution, but apparently only way I found for me